# How would you add non breaking space and ect. in the text?

Tags: javascript, css

The target is to display a string like this:

> Apple, Banana, Lemon

Assume it's in an array.

`const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon']`

1. I would like to join this array with comma and a spaces. how would you do?

New design comes, they wanna show

> Apple,  Banana,   Lemon

combine with comma, double nbsp and emoji.

2. How would you restructure the first implementation?

Comment: The second one is *horrible*. You're constructing HTML as a string, for a start. Next up, it's so much harder to read, as it's way bigger. It also doesn't make sense unless you find out the CSS rule. Oh, and you better hope there aren't any overrides. Sure, a space is a bit hard to notice but it's not THAT hard. A monospaced font will help a lot more than shoving raw HTML into strings.

Comment: _“too easy to overlook by co-worker”_ - then properly _document_ it, f.e. via an inline comment in close proximity to such lines …?

Comment: @04FS eh, I wouldn't trust comments for documentation that much. But you can at least write self-documenting code `space = " "; arr.join("," + space)`. Then again, I would say that even this is an overkill. Spaces aren't THAT hard to notice, usually. Every single editor I've used even has an option to show whitespace characters if *really* needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add HTML, you should create it properly. [Define](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) a wrapper and [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) over the items in the array to add them to it.

As for the space, adding a whitespace character is never a good idea. If you want to create space between elements, use CSS [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) / [margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

```js
const array = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon'];
const wrapper = document.createElement("div");

for (const item of array) {
  const itemWrapper = document.createElement("span");
  itemWrapper.classList.add('space');
  itemWrapper.innerText = item;
  wrapper.append(itemWrapper);
}

document.documentElement.append(wrapper);
```

```css
.space {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```